# Biblatex publication (year) in bold

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am trying to display the year and also the parentheses in bold

> Author **(year)**:

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%Bibliotheken
\usepackage
[style=ext-authoryear,labelnumber, useprefix=true,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=3,uniquelist=false, backend=biber, 
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
uniquename=false,bibencoding=utf8, date=year, giveninits=true, terseinits=false, dashed=false]
{biblatex}


%Colon after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\mkbibbold{\addcolon}\space}

%Year and parantheses in bold
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{parens}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@Article{Hansen2011,
  author  = {Hansen, Peter R. and Lunde, Asger and Nason, James M.},
  title   = {The Model Confidence Set},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {79},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {453-497},
  url     = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:ecm:emetrp:v:79:y:2011:i:2:p:453-497},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib} 

\begin{document}
\textcite{Hansen2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried using \mkbibbold in some way, but it didnt work well. A short explanation would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex-ext` defines additional formats for fields, and among them `biblabeldate` which controls the "format for the labeldate in the bibliography for `authoryear`-like styles", so that's what you have to use for your purpose:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}
```

Besides that, even though you technically can redefine `nametitledelim` with `\renewcommand`, as `nametitledelim` is a context sensitive delimiter, in using `\renewcommand` you lose this context sensitivity. So, you are better off using the proper dedicated `\DeclareDelimFormat`:

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
```

(for this to include the colon in bold font, as set in the formatting directive for `biblabeldate` the option `punctfont=true` is required).

In full:

```
\documentclass[12pt, bibliography=totocnumbered, listof=totoc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}

%Bibliotheken
\usepackage
[style=ext-authoryear,labelnumber, useprefix=true,
sorting=nyt,maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=3,uniquelist=false, backend=biber,
doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,
uniquename=false,bibencoding=utf8, date=year, giveninits=true, terseinits=false,
dashed=false, punctfont=true]
{biblatex}


%Colon after year
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

%Year and parantheses in bold
\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{\mkbibbold{\mkbibparens{#1}}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname2.bib}
@Article{Hansen2011,
  author  = {Hansen, Peter R. and Lunde, Asger and Nason, James M.},
  title   = {The Model Confidence Set},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  year    = {2011},
  volume  = {79},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {453-497},
  url     = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:ecm:emetrp:v:79:y:2011:i:2:p:453-497},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname2.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{Hansen2011}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}...` would be prettier than `\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}...`. If you set the `punctfont` option to true it should not even be necessary to add the `\mkbibbold`, the format of the previous field would automatically be applied to the following punctuation.

Comment: @moewe The answer's "prettification" is duly done. Thank you! Btw, if I'm not mistaken, this must be my first `biblatex-ext` answer.  :-)

Comment: The `\setpunctfont{\textbf}` is superfluous since you are using `\mkbibbold` in the field format. The `\mkbib...` commands execute the appropriate `\setpunctfont` automatically.

Comment: @moewe I see, neat. As a matter of fact, I didn't really know `punctfont` existed (or didn't remember...). But, in general, is it usually safe to assume that the following punctuation mark will obey the previous field formatting directive? It is not really intuitive (true, it makes sense in light of the punctuation tracker).

Comment: If `punctfont` is active and all field formats use the `\mkbib...` commands then the following punctuation command will use the same font (italic, bold, upright). If it works properly this is quite intuitive I think, at least if you want this to happen.

Comment: @moewe I see what you mean from the point of view of output, it does make sense. However, as the punctuation tracker actually prints the punctuation when the following field is printed, I assume there is quite a lot of work being done in the background for this to happen. Probably, I just need some "getting used to".  ;-)